# The following From address failed: webdeveloper.hadi@gmail.com : Called Mail() without being connected

Tags: phpmailer

Guys I Got his error it is working @ localhost but does't work on my host

```
http://myownprojects.co.nf/ ?? 
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "webdeveloper.hadi@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = '**********';
$mail->setFrom("webdeveloper.hadi@gmail.com");
$mail->Subject= "Your confirmation Mail";
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage('images/me.jpg', 'meimg', 'images/me.jpg');     
$mail->Body = "Please click on the link";
$mail->addAddress(webdeveloper.hadi@gmail.com);
if($mail->Send()){
}else{
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using [the latest PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), basing your code on [the gmail example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps) provided, reading the docs, and possibly searching for this same question?

Comment: I have using lqtest PHPMailer basing your above gmail example now i have getting error "Extension missing: openssl"; I have got free hostin by this site http://cp1.biz.nf/beta/

Comment: Then you need to find a host that has a proper PHP config.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->Port = 587;
```